# How to test that an actor created at the start of a Play! application receives a message?

Tags: scala, testing, playframework, akka, guice

For every client connecting to my Play! 2.5 Scala application, a webSocket is opened.

I have an actor created at the beginning of the application with  `AkkaGuiceSupport` :

```
bindActor[RoomsActor]("rooms")
```

When a webSocket is opened, it sends a message to this actor and I want to test that the message is well sent.

How can I do this?

**Edit:** please note that I know `TestActorRef` and `TestProbe()` but I think that I cannot use them. Indeed, I can not use `TestActorRef` because I don't have the reference of the actor that is created at the application start. I also cannot use a `Probe` since I never pass the sender or the receiver (actors) as an argument of an other actor : the receiver is created as application start and the sender is created in the controller as following:

```
def openClientSocket = WebSocket.acceptOrResult[ChatEvent, ChatEvent] { request =>
    ...
    ActorFlow.actorRef(ChatWebSocketActor.props())
    ...
}
```

Comment: How to test depends on your structure. Also, there are some helper functions etc. provided by akka: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/testing.html

Comment: @rethab I have already read the doc (and already testing other actors) and I'm telling you the structure of my application in my question. I can not use TestActorRef because I don't have the reference of the actor that is created at the application start. I also cannot use a Probe since I never pass the sender or the receiver (actors) as an argument of an other actor.